# How would you style text like a fraction?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a styling question where I want the font to look similar to my crummy MSPaint example.

I have tried a myriad a of things like using bootstrap and trying to build it through the grid system but there was some pretty bad white-space issues and it did not scale well.

[image: What I would like it to look like.]

The help would be amazing.

Comment: Just a quick try at this - perhaps 2 `<span>` tags side-by-side, with the left-side having 2 times the `line-height` of the other. In your right-side `<span>`, write the text like `<span>%<br>OFF</span>`

Comment: Showing the non-working work would be good, that way people would know what not to suggest.

Comment: I understand, I will make sure to do that next time. Thank you for the input.

Answer (score 4):

you can add the % off with a pseudo element

```css
.discount {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  font-size: 40px;
}
.discount::after {
  content: "% off";
  display: block;
  left: 100%;
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 18px;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div class="discount">50</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use grid and flex to achieve this

```css
.row {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 2fr 1fr;
    width: 50px;
}

.row .col {
    font-size: 3rem;
}

.row .col2 {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    font-size: 1.3rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
    <div class="col">
        50
    </div>
    <div class="col2">
        <div class="top">
            %
        </div>
        <div class="bottom">Off</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this one...

```
<h3 style="display: inline-block;">
    50  <sub style="margin-left: -4%;">off</sub>
    <sup style="margin-left: -32%;"> % 
   </sup>    
</h3>
```

Answer (score 0):

Find the complete code below for custom and normal fractional representation:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Fraction</title>
  <style>
    * {
      font-family: sans-serif;
      font-weight: 600;
    }
    
    .wn {
      font-size: 45px;
    }
    
    .frac {
      display: inline-block;
      position: relative;
      letter-spacing: 0.001em;
    }
    
    .frac>span {
      display: block;
      padding: 0.1em;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <h3>To display custom fraction</h3>
  <div><span class="wn">50</span>
    <div class="frac">
      <span>%</span>
      <span class="bottom">OFF</span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <hr>
  <h3>To display normal fractional representation</h3>
  <div>1 &frac12;</div>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this (if you need separate `%` and `OFF` to style them separately):

```css
.discount{
  position: relative;
  font-size: 40pt;
  font-weight: bold;
}
.discount:after{
  content:"%";
  position: absolute;
  top:0;
  left: 100%;
  font-size: 18pt;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.discount:before{
  content:"OFF";
  position: absolute;
  bottom:0;
  left: 100%;
  font-size: 18pt;
}
```

```html
<span class="discount">50</span>
```